# Running Vagrant from external disk on 2 different computers

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

i want to use my vagrant VBox image (Debian) on 2 ore more different Windows 7 PCs, because a lot of settings and data (e.g. DB, Vhost) are already in place. I'm using the image for different projects and just make a new vagrant-vbox-image when i need other OS, PHP etc. versions.

So i installed Vagrant and Virtualbox on both machines, changed the path of the Virtualbox-Images to my external disk via Virtualbox Manager and also changed the path of /.vagrant.d to the external disk by setting an environment variable for VAGRANT_HOME. On both machines. Now it works on one machine, but i can't start the image on the other one.

I'm using the latest VBox 4.3.15. i tried to start the image with "vagrant up", but this tries to install me a new image from the box defined and gives me this error:

```
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not rename the directory 'W:\VirtualBox VMs\boxes_default_1383360377_1408558738514_43554' to 'W:\VirtualBox VMs\dev_deb720' to save the settings file (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
```

And adding the existing image to the VBox Manger by just clicking in the .vbox and then starting it from there just brings up an error:

```
Fehlercode:E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Komponente:Machine
Interface:IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

So has anyone tried to do the same and can descrobe how the same vagrant-vbox-image can be used on different machines? Or some hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

While I never tried to do what you describe, 
I think the reason your second machine is re-creating your vagrant environment is because you didn't copy '.vagrant' folder from first machine to the second.

`VAGRANT_HOME` is the global state folder. But when you create new environment with `vagrant up` you also create local state folder in the same folder as your Vagrantfile called `.vagrant`.

If this folder doesn't exists, Vagrant will recreate your environment (unless you changed the default behaviour of Vagrant via environment variables).

Generally, I think it's really bad idea to work like this because it's totally against Vagrant's initial intent for creating "lightweight, reproducible and portable development environments". You should consider adding your settings/data into the base box, adding it via provisioning or using [Vagrant Share](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/index.html) for sharing live machine.

Comment: All relevant folders are on the external disk, also the .vagrant folder where i start the machine. And like i mentioned also the VAGRANT_HOME and the VBox-Images. So this can't be the case, there must be something still existing on the Host-PCs, that causes this Problem :-(


And i know know that vagrant is not intended or optimal for may use case, but it  should be possible, or? Changing my whole workflow is actually not possible, because a lot of people int he company working with this.

Comment: @MuckyBuzzwoo is it always the same machine that gives you the error or is it always the second one?

Comment: Same for me ... using vagrant 1.9.1 and VirtualBox 5.1 on 2 Win7/64 machines. Frustrating ....